# Data Version Control: Absolute Paths and Project Paths in the Pipeline Parameters?

Tags: git, path, dvc

In DVC one may define pipelines.  In Unix, one typically does not work at the root level.  Further, DVC expects files to be inside the git repository.

So, this seems like a typical problem.

Suppose I have the following:

```
/home/user/project/content-folder/data/data-type/cfg.json
/home/user/project/content-folder/app/foo.py
```

Git starts at `/home/user/project/`

```
cd ~/project/content-folder/data/data-type
../../app/foo.py do-this --with cfg.json --dest $(pwd)
```

Seems reasonable to me: the script takes a configuration, which is stored in a particular location, runs it against some encapsulated functionality, and outputs it to the destination using an absolute path.

The default behavior of `--dest` is to output to the current working directory.  This seems like another reasonable default.

---

Next, I go to configure the `params.yaml` file for `dvc`, and I am immediately confusing and unsure what is going to happen.  I write:

```
foodoo:
  params: do-this --with ????/cfg.json --dest ????
```

What I want to write (and would in a shell script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
origin:=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

verb=do-this
params=--with $(origin)/content-folder/data/data-type/cfg.json --dest $(origin)/content-folder/data/data-type
```

---

But, in DVC, the pathing seems to be implicit, and I do not know where to start as either:

1. DVC will calculate the path to my script locally
2. Not calculate the path to my script locally

Which is fine -- I can discover that.  But I am reasonably sure that DVC will absolutely not prefix the directory and file params in my params.yaml with the path to my project.

---

How does one achieve path control that does not assume a fixed project location, like I would in BASH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, DVC will run your stage command from the same directory as the [dvc.yaml](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/dvc-files#dvcyaml-file) file. If you need to run the command from a different location, you can specify an alternate working directory via `wdir`, which should be a path relative to `dvc.yaml`'s location.

Paths for everything else in your stage (like `params.yaml`) should be specified as relative to `wdir` (or relative to `dvc.yaml` if `wdir` is not provided).

Looking at your example, there also seems to be a bit of confusion on parameters in DVC. In a DVC stage, `params` is for specifying [parameter dependencies](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/params), not used for specifying command-line flags. The full command including flags/options should be included  the `cmd` section for your stage. If you wanted to make sure that your stage was rerun every time certain values in `cfg.json` have changed, your stage's `params` section would look something like:

```
params:
  <relpath from dvc.yaml>/cfg.json:
    - param1
    - param2
    ...
```

So your example `dvc.yaml` would look something like:

```
stages:
  foodoo:
    cmd: <relpath from dvc.yaml>/foo.py do-this --with <relpath from dvc.yaml>/cfg.json --dest <relpath from dvc.yaml>/...
    deps:
      <relpath from dvc.yaml>/foo.py
    params:
      <relpath from dvc.yaml>/cfg.json:
        ...
    ...
```

This would make the command `dvc repro` rerun your stage any time that the code in foo.py has changed, or the specified parameters in `cfg.json` have changed.

You may also want to refer to the docs for [dvc run](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/run#run), which can be used to generate or update a `dvc.yaml` stage (rather than writing `dvc.yaml` by hand)

Comment: Great! I got frustrated for a little while, until I figured out that DVC did not make any of the mistakes I expected, and was much more than anticipated.